# How to configure dhcpd.conf so that the ssid appears to have an internet connection?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have my raspberry pi configured as a hotspot with its own ssid that my iPhone can connect to. When the iPhone connects to the pi's ssid, it gives me a warning saying that "This network is not connected to the internet."

How can I fix this so that the iPhone thinks the pi's ssid is connected to the internet? interfaces file? dhcpd.conf?

Comment: This is a question about how iPhones decide they have an internet connection.  (Android phones do it by seeing if they can retrieve a particular file from Google, and I believe Windows PCs do a similar thing from Microsoft.  I don't know about iPhones.)  Once you know that, maybe you can ask here how to implement it on a Pi.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  Does the Raspberry Pi also have an Internet connection and you want to use it as a gateway?  A message indicating that it doesn't have an Internet connection isn't necessarily indicating an error -- that's just an information message.  If it really is supposed to have an Internet connection, then it means the Pi isn't offering some required services (such as routing between networks and/or possibly NAT translation).

Comment: @TimCampbell, I do not have the Pi connected to the internet. I have it set up as an ad-hoc AP so that I can connect with the phone, transfer the credentials for a proper wifi network to the Pi from the phone, and have the Pi reboot and connect to the proper wifi network. The problem is that the "no internet" message is preventing my iOS framework from connecting automatically behind the scenes. I'd like to remedy this by pretending the pi has an internet connection.

Comment: Which OS are you running (e.g. Rasbian, Ubuntu, etc.)?  You can open a terminal and type `cat /etc/os-release` to find this.  Also, does your Pi OS run a graphical desktop vs. command-line access?

Comment: @TimCampbell, Raspbian Stretch Lite.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tcpdump` on the Pi to see what your iphone is trying to connect to and fetch, and fake that! This won't work, of course, if the iphone tries to fetch from an https page and checks the cert.